# How to extract the name of the authors using an XPath expression

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver, xpath-1.0

Given below is the snippet of HTML:

```
<div class="a-row a-spacing-none">
    <span class="a-size-small a-color-secondary">by 
    </span>
    <span class="a-size-small a-color-secondary">
        <a class="a-link-normal a-text-normal" href="/Lowell-Fryman/e/B01M3MNJTE/ref=sr_ntt_srch_lnk_1?qid=1550228622&amp;sr=1-1">
        Lowell Fryman
        </a> 
        and 
    </span>
    <span class="a-size-small a-color-secondary">
        <a class="a-link-normal a-text-normal" href="/Gregory-Lampshire/e/B01N7ZWT5Y/ref=sr_ntt_srch_lnk_1?qid=1550228622&amp;sr=1-1">
        Gregory Lampshire
        </a>
    </span>
</div>
```

I'm trying to obtain the name of all authors.
This is whatever test follows the word `by`. 
I came up with the following XPath but it doesn't seem to fetch all the authors.

My XPath expression:

```
//div//span[text()=\"by \"]//following::span[1]//a
```

Can someone please tell me how to obtain the name of all the authors while somehow managing to skip any element whose text is "and"?

I'm using Selenium's `find_element_by_xpath` if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code.This should work.It will fetch all author.

```
elements=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='a-link-normal a-text-normal']")

for element in elements:
    print(element.text)
```

Please let me know if this work.

Answer (score 1):

Here xpath you can use to get authors:

```
//div[./span[normalize-space(.='by')]]//a
```

or

```
//div[./span[contains(.,'by')]]//a
```

Your xpath should be like this:

```
//span[normalize-space(.='by')]/following-sibling::span//a
```

Answer (score 1):

you can first get text of all span elements in a list and then slice it from "by" text value

```
elements = [_.text() for _ in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.span')]
print elements[elements.index('by'):]
```

Answer (score 0):

To print the name of all the authors which are followed by the word **by** you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `innerHTML`:

  ```
  print([author.get_attribute("innerHTML") for author in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[contains(., 'by')]//following::span/a[@class='a-link-normal a-text-normal'][@href]")])
  ```
- Using `text`:

  ```
  print([author.text for author in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[contains(., 'by')]//following::span/a[@class='a-link-normal a-text-normal'][@href]")])
  ```